# Styles not getting applied toddams/RazorLight razor engine html to PDF conversion

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, razorlight

Used toddams/RazorLight razor engine saved web pages and converted tp pdf, used .schtml file conversion, converted webpage as string for html to pdf conversion but styles do not get applied when converted to pdf.